# Can any one explain how the yarn lock works?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I'm creating docker image on node.js 10 version and same thing was working before but now our image build is failing because of these below error

```
error @azure/core-auth@1.3.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.0.0". Got "10.23.2"
```

error Found incompatible module.

I can fix that above issue with

```
yarn install --ignore-engines
```

But in future which will lead some issue, so I don't want want to use `--ignore-engines` flags.

In package.json file I'm specifically passing the specific version

```
 "devDependencies": {
"@azure/core-auth":"1.3.0" 
}
```

when I looked into yarn.lock file I see the duplicate package with different version

`"@azure/core-auth@1.3.0": version "1.3.0" resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@azure/core-auth/-/core-auth-1.3.0.tgz#0d55517cf0650aefe755669aca8a2f3724fcf536" integrity sha512-kSDSZBL6c0CYdhb+7KuutnKGf2geeT+bCJAgccB0DD7wmNJSsQPcF7TcuoZX83B7VK4tLz/u+8sOO/CnCsYp8A== dependencies: "@azure/abort-controller" "^1.0.0" tslib "^2.0.0"`

`"@azure/core-auth@^1.1.3", "@azure/core-auth@^1.1.4", "@azure/core-auth@^1.3.0": version "1.3.2" resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@azure/core-auth/-/core-auth-1.3.2.tgz#6a2c248576c26df365f6c7881ca04b7f6d08e3d0" integrity sha512-7CU6DmCHIZp5ZPiZ9r3J17lTKMmYsm/zGvNkjArQwPkrLlZ1TZ+EUYfGgh2X31OLMVAQCTJZW4cXHJi02EbJnA== dependencies: "@azure/abort-controller" "^1.0.0" tslib "^2.2.0"`

can anyone explain me why I'm seeing these two version of package, why yarn is not honoring the package.json?  How to resolve these issue?

I can manually remove that from yarn.lock file and it works fine, but I could like to avoid that.

Comment: Presumably because, although you've specified 1.3.0 exactly, some of your dependencies give you a transitive dependency on the broader semver - you can see them listed: ^1.1.3, ^1.1.4, ^1.3.0. You could use https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/ or, given that Node 10 is out of LTS now, upgrade Node.